# Using GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate provides error

Tags: flutter

EDIT:
Answer was very simple:

```
await initializeDateFormatting('pl_PL');
```

Above code was in conflict with:

```
GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate
```

Removing initializeDateFormatting helps.

---

I made a localization on my Flutter app. Unfortunately when I add `GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate` to `localizationsDelegates` there is an error. Removing `GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate` provides app to work correctly but only English version. Another language (Polish) has a problem with AppBars (Again - after removing it (appbar) app works fine in that language too).

Part of my code:

```
localizationsDelegates: [
  const ReadyLocalizationsDelegate(),
  GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
  GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
],
supportedLocales: [
  const Locale('en', 'US'),
  const Locale('pl', 'PL'),
],
```

Error:

> Unsupported operation: Cannot set value in unmodifiable Map

Here is an error when I comment GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate (page has AppBar):
https://pastebin.com/ENF5ZET7

As I said there is no error when localization is set to English.

Comment: Is this Android or iOS?

Comment: A complete runnable minimal reproduction would be helpful.

Comment: It was tested on Android version. I have to create new project and copy some part of app. I will upload it in 20-30 minutes on github.

Comment: Finally I found the solution: there was a conflict of dateFormatting - on app initialize there was: await initializeDateFormatting('pl_PL'); Removing it helps.

Comment: How can we do to keep the two things ?

Comment: @Adrien try replacing `await initializeDateFormatting('pl_PL');` with `Intl.defaultLocale = 'pl_PL';`

Comment: Thanks @Pavel, this works for me!

Comment: @edi_smooth Why dont you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`await initializeDateFormatting('pl_PL');`

Above code was in conflict with:

`GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate`

Removing initializeDateFormatting helps.

Comment: I finally found this answer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You saved me aswell. It's still available for Flutter 3.3.3. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I literally was stuck on this so much time. thank you, this literally saved my night.
Cheers.

Answer (score 9):

If you just want to use the system's locale setting, there is no need to call initializeDateFormatting(). In your main.dart before calling runApp(), do this:

```
await findSystemLocale();
```

To call this method, you will need this import:

```
import 'package:intl/intl_standalone.dart';
```

As a reference, there is some documentation here -- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/Intl/systemLocale.html

Comment: I was trying to use ```await initializeDateFormatting("es_ES")``` but this ```await findSystemLocale();``` has saved me, thanks.