# Using showDatePicker with Locale causes Unsupported operation

Tags: flutter, dart, datepicker

I try to use showDatePicker with a locale.

```
showDatePicker(
                    locale: const Locale('de'),
                    context: context,
```

And if I have localizationsDelegates in MaterialApp

```
MaterialApp(
  title: appTitle,
  theme: ImpexStyle.mainTheme,
  darkTheme: ImpexStyle.mainTheme,
  locale: const Locale('de'),
  localizationsDelegates: [
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
  ],
  supportedLocales: [
    const Locale('de'),
  ],
```

I get **Unsupported operation: Cannot set value in unmodifiable Map**

Comment: are you using initializeDateFormatting ?

Comment: See if this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459261/using-globalmateriallocalizations-delegate-provides-error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

doesn't work together with  initializeDateFormatting